# Angular - How to change variable's color in html file in VS Code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Question has been asked before, but with no answers.

I have this snippets in html and ts component files:

[image]

[image]

I would like to have the variables: `allowNewServer` and `serverCreationStatus` colored purple.
My VS Code plug-ins:
Angular Essentials (Version 9)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code, changing color theme for variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954433/vs-code-changing-color-theme-for-variables)

Comment: @CodeWarrior Thanks for the suggestion. I have read the answears there before posting the question and they were C/C++ related. In my case I would like a plugin or json property that will change the typescript code as well as the html code to display the variables in purple and not in blue/light blue.

Comment: @VictorValeanu please avoid using images of code. Instead use inline code formatting and paste your actual code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ZekrosAdmines I'm pretty new to asking questions and I couldn't figure out how to color the code in my code template.

Answer (score 4):

I use this [VS Code plugin](https://github.com/ghaschel/vscode-angular-html) that adds syntax highlighting to angular html templates.

To further enhance to color it specifically purple, you'll have to tweak your theme or editors `textMateRules` settings.

In your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": [
            "expression.angular-interpolation",
            "source.directive.angular"
          ],
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "purple" // or use your desired hex code
          }
        },
      ]
  },
```

Comment: I have added the plugin and the property in settings.json with a purple Hex code and unfortunately it colored everything but the variables. I liked how the other things were colored before(classes, functions, key words). I just want the variables to be colored differently. Thanks anyway!

Comment: hmm, then remove the plugin, and find the correct scope for the variables. You can find the correct scope by inspection the editors token and scopes. You can find / add the shortcut by searching for `editor.action.inspectTMScopes` in your keymaps

Comment: After adding all the scopes it turned the variables in purple, but also the equal signs "=" and the function paranthesis "()". It looks like I will have to play around with it until I will get only the right scopes to get colored in purple. Thanks a lot! I will edit your answear with the right scopes after I get it right.